# sonarQube exception shutdown after some time

Tags: sonarqube

Hi i din't get any exception but still sonarQube shutdown after few second

```
root@testmachine:~/sonarqube-7.1/bin/linux-x86-64# ./sonar.sh start
Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.

root@testmachine:~/sonarqube-7.1/bin/linux-x86-64# ./sonar.sh console

Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:46:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /root/sonarqube-7.1/temp
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:46:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:46:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/root/sonarqube-7.1/elasticsearch]: /root/sonarqube-7.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/root/sonarqube-7.1/temp/conf/es
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:46:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:46:12 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:46:12 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:46:14 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:46:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2018.04.26 14:46:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Did you check [all logs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Troubleshooting) ? Anything relevant there ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be executing as `root` , SonarQube does not support that. See [v6.6 Upgrade Note](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Release+6.6+Upgrade+Notes).